# Си. При вызове функции из dll вся программа падает с ошибкой memory access

Tags: c, функции, указатели, dll, память

Есть основная программа:

```
#define BUILD_DLL
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


// Структура листа
struct listlight {
  char MD5[33];                // MD5
  struct listlight* right;         // Правый ребенок
};


// Структура листа
struct list {
  struct listlight* first;
};


// Глобальные переменные
char tmp[33];
HINSTANCE dllp;

//Генератор рандомных md5 сумм
void RadndomMD5(){

    unsigned char i, j;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        j =  (rand()%(17));
        if (j == 0) tmp[i] = '0'; else
        if (j == 1) tmp[i] = '1'; else
        if (j == 2) tmp[i] = '2'; else
        if (j == 3) tmp[i] = '3'; else
        if (j == 4) tmp[i] = '4'; else
        if (j == 5) tmp[i] = '5'; else
        if (j == 6) tmp[i] = '6'; else
        if (j == 7) tmp[i] = '7'; else
        if (j == 8) tmp[i] = '8'; else
        if (j == 9) tmp[i] = '9'; else

        if (j == 10) tmp[i] = 'A'; else
        if (j == 11) tmp[i] = 'B'; else
        if (j == 12) tmp[i] = 'C'; else
        if (j == 13) tmp[i] = 'D'; else
        if (j == 14) tmp[i] = 'E'; else
        if (j == 15) tmp[i] = 'F'; else

        i = 0;

    }
}

bool slm(const char *str1, const char *str2){
 return (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0);
}

void PrintHelp(){
    system("cls");
    printf("Справка:\n\n");
    printf("Строение: \n|основная комманда|дополнительный параметр|ключ|\n");
    printf("\nОсновные комманды: \n");
    printf("|ADD   |First/End    |MD5|            - добавление элемента\n");
    printf("|REMOVE|First/End/VAL|MD5|true/false| - удаление элемента (true - всех элементов)\n");
    printf("|CHECK |             |   |          | - проверка на пустоту\n");
    printf("|FIND  |             |MD5|          | - происк элемента\n");
    printf("|PRINT |             |   |          | - вывод листа\n");
    printf("|CLEAN |             |   |          | - очистка листа\n");
    printf("|EXIT  |             |   |          | - выход из программы\n");


}


void FindFind(struct list* List){

   char tmpword[33];
   unsigned char i;
   bool (__stdcall *List_FindMe)(char MD5[32], struct list* List);


   scanf("%s", tmpword);
   for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) tmpword[i] = toupper(tmpword[i]);

   if (dllp) {
       List_FindMe = (bool(__stdcall *) (char MD5[32], struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_FindMe");
   }

   if (slm(tmpword, "RANDOM")){
      RadndomMD5();
      if (List_FindMe(tmp, List)) printf("true\n"); else printf("false\n");
   } else {
      if (List_FindMe(tmpword, List)) printf("true\n"); else printf("false\n");
   }

}


void AddAdd(struct list* List){
    char tmpword[33];
    char tmppos[33];
    unsigned char i;


    void (__stdcall *List_Add_First)(char MD5[32], struct list* List);
    void (__stdcall *List_Add_End)  (char MD5[32], struct list* List);


   if (dllp) {
       List_Add_First = (void(__stdcall *) (char MD5[32], struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_Add_First");
       List_Add_End   = (void(__stdcall *) (char MD5[32], struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_Add_End");
   }

    scanf("%s%s", tmppos, tmpword);

    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++){
     tmpword[i] = toupper(tmpword[i]);
     tmppos[i] = toupper(tmppos[i]);
    }

    if (slm(tmppos, "FIRST")) {

       if (slm(tmpword, "RANDOM")){
         RadndomMD5();
         List_Add_First(tmp, List);
       } else {
         List_Add_First(tmpword, List);
       }

    } else
    if (slm(tmppos, "END")) {
       if (slm(tmpword, "RANDOM")){
         RadndomMD5();
         List_Add_End(tmp, List);
       } else {
         List_Add_End(tmpword, List);
       }
    }

}


void RemoveRemove(struct list* List){
    char tmpword[33];
    char tmppos[33];
    unsigned char i;

    void (__stdcall *List_RemoveFirst)(struct list* List);
    void (__stdcall *List_RemoveLast) (struct list* List);
    void (__stdcall *List_RemoveValue)(char MD5[32], struct list* List, bool All);

   if (dllp) {
       List_RemoveFirst = (void(__stdcall *) (struct list* List)) GetProcAddress                        (dllp, "_List_RemoveFirst");
       List_RemoveLast  = (void(__stdcall *) (struct list* List)) GetProcAddress                        (dllp, "_List_RemoveLast");
       List_RemoveValue = (void(__stdcall *) (char MD5[32], struct list* List, bool All)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_RemoveValue");
   }

    scanf("%s", tmppos);

    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) tmppos[i] = toupper(tmppos[i]);

    if (slm(tmppos, "FIRST")) List_RemoveFirst(List); else
    if (slm(tmppos, "END"))   List_RemoveLast(List); else
    if (slm(tmppos, "VAL")){

       scanf("%s%s", tmppos, tmpword);

       for (i = 0; i < 33; i++){
         tmpword[i] = toupper(tmpword[i]);
         tmppos[i]  = toupper(tmppos[i]);
       }

       if (slm(tmppos, "RANDOM")) {
         RadndomMD5();
         for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) tmppos[i] = toupper(tmp[i]);
       }

       if (slm(tmpword, "TRUE" )) List_RemoveValue(tmppos, List, true); else List_RemoveValue(tmppos, List, false);

    }

}


void PrintPrint(struct list* List){
   void (__stdcall *List_PrintMe)(struct list* List);

   if (dllp) {
       List_PrintMe = (void(__stdcall *) (struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_PrintMe");
   }

   List_PrintMe(List);

}


void CheckCheck(struct list* List){
   bool (__stdcall *List_IsEmpty)(struct list* List);

   if (dllp) {
       List_IsEmpty = (bool(__stdcall *) (struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_IsEmpty");
   }

   if (List_IsEmpty(List)) printf("true\n"); else printf("false\n");

}


void FreeFree(struct list* List){

     void (__stdcall *List_FreeAndNil)(struct list* List);

     if (dllp) {
           List_FreeAndNil = (void(__stdcall *) (struct list* List)) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_FreeAndNil");
     }

     List_FreeAndNil(List);

}


int main(){

    // Переменные
    bool exitkey;
    char tmpword[257];
    int i;
    struct list* MyList;

    dllp = LoadLibrary("DinLib.dll");

    struct list* (__stdcall *List_Create)();

    // Начальная инициализация листа
    dllp = LoadLibrary("DinLib.dll");
    if (dllp) {
           List_Create = (struct list*(__stdcall *) ()) GetProcAddress(dllp, "_List_Create");
    }

    MyList = List_Create();


    RadndomMD5();

    // Фикс кириллицы
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    // Вывод приветствия
    printf("Добро пожаловать!\nПрограмму выполнил: Буренков Игорь (М80-206Б-17)\n\nведите h или help для вывода справки\n");

    // Панель ввода вывода

    while (exitkey != true){

        // Печать t> перед командой
        printf("t>");

        // Считываем первое слово
        scanf("%s", tmpword);

        // Перевод слова в верхний регистр
        for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) tmpword[i] = toupper(tmpword[i]);

        // Анализ первой комманды

        if (slm(tmpword, "H")||slm(tmpword, "HELP")) PrintHelp(); else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "PRINT"))  PrintPrint(MyList);             else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "FIND"))   FindFind(MyList);               else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "CHECK"))  CheckCheck(MyList);         else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "ADD"))    AddAdd(MyList);                 else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "REMOVE")) RemoveRemove(MyList);           else
        //if (slm(tmpword, "CLEAN"))  FreeFree(MyList);               else
        if (slm(tmpword, "EXIT")) exitkey= true;

    }

    FreeFree(MyList);
    free(MyList);

    FreeLibrary(dllp);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При вызове функции, например *List_Add_First(tmp, List);* программа падает.

DLL же представляет собой два файла

mainlib.h:

```
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
# define DLL_EXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
# if defined(BUILD_APP)
# define DLL_EXP __declspec(dllimport)
# else
# define DLL_EXP
# endif
#endif


// Стандартные заголовки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


// Структура листа
struct listlight;

// Структура листа
struct list;

// Создание узла листа
DLL_EXP struct list* List_Create();

// Уничтожение листа
DLL_EXP void List_FreeAndNil(struct list* List);

// Проверка на пустоту
DLL_EXP bool List_IsEmpty(struct list* List);

// Добавить элемент-лист в начало
DLL_EXP void List_Add_First(char MD5[32], struct list* List);

// Добавить элемент-лист в конец
DLL_EXP void List_Add_End(char MD5[32], struct list* List);

// Удаление первого листа
DLL_EXP void List_RemoveFirst(struct list* List);

// Удаление последнего листо
 DLL_EXP void List_RemoveLast(struct list* List);

 // Удаление листа по значениею
 DLL_EXP void List_RemoveValue(char MD5[32], struct list* List, bool All);

// Поиск значения
 DLL_EXP bool List_FindMe(char MD5[32], struct list* List);

// Печать элементы
 DLL_EXP void List_PrintMe(struct list* List);
```

mainlib.c:

```
#define BUILD_DLL
#include "mainlib.h"


// Структура листа
struct listlight {
  char MD5[33];                // MD5
  struct listlight* right;     // Правый ребенок
};


// Структура листа
struct list {
  struct listlight* first;
};


// Создание листа
DLL_EXP struct list* List_Create(){
  struct list* List = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  List->first = NULL;
  return List;
}


// Уничтожение листа
DLL_EXP void List_FreeAndNil(struct list* List) {
  // Запускаем балалайку ^_^
  //while (List_IsEmpty(List) == false) {
  //    List_RemoveLast(List);
  //}
  return;
}


// Проверка на пустоту
DLL_EXP bool List_IsEmpty(struct list* List){
  return (List->first == NULL);
}


// Инициализация элемента списка
DLL_EXP struct listlight* Leaf_inside_Create(char MD5[32]){

    // Переменные
    struct listlight* tmp;
    unsigned char i;

    // Начальная инициализация
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct listlight));
    tmp->right = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) tmp->MD5[i] = MD5[i];

    // Возращаем указатель
    return tmp;
}


// Добавление листа в конец
DLL_EXP void List_Add_End(char MD5[33], struct list* List){

    // Указатель на новый элемент
    struct listlight* tmp = Leaf_inside_Create(MD5);
    struct listlight* current;

    // Вставляем указатель
    if (List_IsEmpty(List)) {
      List->first = tmp;
    } else {
      current = List->first;
      while (current->right != NULL) current = current->right;
      current->right = tmp;
    }
}


// Добавление листа в начало
DLL_EXP void List_Add_First(char MD5[33], struct list* List){

    // Указатель на новый элемент
    struct listlight* tmp = Leaf_inside_Create(MD5);

    // Временный контейнер
    struct listlight* current;

    // Вставляем указатель
    if (List_IsEmpty(List)) {
      List->first = tmp;
    } else {
      tmp->right = List->first;
      List->first = tmp;
    }
}


// Удаление  первого элемента
DLL_EXP void List_RemoveFirst(struct list* List){

    // Временный контейнер
    struct listlight* tmp;

    // Если лист не пустой
    if (List_IsEmpty(List) == false) {

        // Запоминаем 2ю позицию
        tmp = List->first->right;

        // Освобождение памяти
        free(List->first);

        // Делаем 2ю позицию первой
        List->first = tmp;
    }
}

// Удаление последнего элемента
DLL_EXP void List_RemoveLast(struct list* List){

    // Временный контейнер
    struct listlight* tmp = List->first;

    if (tmp == NULL) return;

    if (tmp->right == NULL) {
        List_RemoveFirst(List);
        return;
    }

    while (tmp->right->right != NULL) tmp = tmp->right;

    free(tmp->right);
    tmp->right = NULL;

}

//Сравнить две MD5 суммы
DLL_EXP bool EquivalentMD5(char MD5left[33], char MD5right[33]){

   unsigned char i;

   for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) if (MD5left[i] != MD5right[i]) return false;

   return true;
}

// Удалить по значению
DLL_EXP void List_RemoveValue(char MD5[33], struct list* List, bool All){

    // Переменные
    unsigned char i;
    struct listlight* tmp = List->first;
    struct listlight* tmp2;


    if (tmp == NULL) return;

    if (EquivalentMD5(tmp->MD5, MD5)) {
        List_RemoveFirst(List);
        if (All == false) return;
    }

    while (tmp->right != NULL){
       if (EquivalentMD5(tmp->right->MD5, MD5)) {
           if (tmp->right->right == NULL) List_RemoveLast(List);
               else{
                   tmp2 = tmp->right->right;
                   free(tmp->right);
                   tmp->right = tmp2;
               }
           if (All == false) return;
       }
    }
}


// Поиск значения
DLL_EXP bool List_FindMe(char MD5[33], struct list* List){

    struct listlight* tmp = List->first;

    while (tmp != NULL){
        if (EquivalentMD5(tmp->MD5, MD5)) return true;
        tmp = tmp->right;
    }

    return false;
}


// Печать элементы
DLL_EXP void List_PrintMe(struct list* List){

   struct listlight* tmp = List->first;
   unsigned char i;

   while (tmp != NULL){
        printf("%c", '|');
        for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
           printf("%c", tmp->MD5[i]);
        }
        tmp = tmp->right;
   }
   printf("%c%c", '|', '\n');
}
```

Если данную библиотеку подключить, как .lib (статично) - все работает, а, как dll, почему-то нет.

Ссылка на проект: https://yadi.sk/d/390OeXKfXdiBcg (Static - .lib, Unstatic - .dll)

Искренне уповаю на вашу помощь, т.к. только учусь работе с подобными библиотеками и возможно что-то не понимаю

Comment: Делал по туториалу из Касперского и от сюда: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/bcb/dll.php

Comment: Ну и для чего у вас предназначен символ `BUILD_APP`? Где он используется? И почему у вас в начале главной программы делается `#define BUILD_DLL`???

Comment: Проблема в передаче указателей на динамическую память через границы DLL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries?view=vs-2019 Так делать не рекомендуется, потому что это будет корректно работать только когда EXE и DLL используют одну и ту же стандартную библиотеку С (по версии и по варианту debug/release)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight и как тогда быть, т..к. мне нужно работать с указателями!

Comment: Работать с указателями можно, и нужно. Нельзя делать free в EXE на указатель, возвращенный из DLL, и наоборот. Но у вас похоже есть более серьезная проблема. В DLL `struct list* List_Create();`, а в EXE  `struct list* (__stdcall *List_Create)();`. Откуда взялся __stdcall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что ваша DLL слинкована с библиотекой времени выполнения MSVC *статически*. Тогда ваша DLL обладает своим внутренним менеджером динамической памяти, т.е. своей кучей. Каждый раз, когда вы выполняете `LoadLibrary`, вы создаете эту кучу "с нуля", а каждый раз, когда вы выполняете `FreeLibrary`, вы уничтожаете эту кучу со всеми хранящимися в ней данными.

Поэтому каждый раз, когда вы делаете `FreeLibrary`, вы уничтожаете все, что вы только что создали в куче данной DLL. Любые попытки работы со вашим списком после `FreeLibrary` приведут к падению программы.

Прекратите делать эти постоянные `LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary`. Раз уж вы хотите подгружать DLL вручную (почему, кстати?), то `LoadLibrary` должен делаться только один раз в самом начале работы со списками, а `FreeLibrary` - тогда когда списки вам уже не нужны. Обычно `LoadLibrary` делается один раз в начале работы программы, а `FreeLibrary` - один раз в самом конце.

---

Побочное замечание:

Вам "повезло", что в `mainlib.h` первым идет объявление функции

```
DLL_EXP struct list* List_Create();
```

которое упоминает тип `struct list` в рамках своего *типа возвращаемого значения* (а не в списке параметров). Это автоматически создает и глобальное объявление типа `struct list`, на которое ссылаются все последующие объявления.

Однако более разумной практикой было бы предоставить самостоятельное объявление типа `struct list` где-то в самом начале `mainlib.h`

```
struct list;
```

чтобы "объявленность" этого типа не зависела от того, какая функция будет объявлена первой.

Также, функции без параметров в языке С рекомендуется объявлять с явным `(void)`. Объявления с `()` являются deprecated.

Comment: Спасибо. 2ю часть поправил

Comment: А вот с первой не все так радужно: на функции List_Add_First как вылетало - так вылетает. Только раньше ошибка была Write Access Error, а теперь System Exeption 0x00...01

Comment: Мне кажется дело в доступности указателей

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: Я не знаю, о какой доступности указателей вы говорите. Мне также не ясно, где у вас вообще `__declspec(dllexport)`, почему имена в `GetProcAddress` начинаются с `_` и что такое `#define BUILD_DLL`. Я исправил эти странности - у меня все работает.

Comment: Также не ясно, что это за постоянный странный дребезг между `32` и `33` в размерах массивов.

Comment: Выделил фрагмент освобождения памяти, который вызывает пустую функцию. НО! Даже так вылетает ошибка

Comment: Можете исправленный вариант скинуть, чтоб наглядно сравнить